# How can I check if the given URL of an image exists using GWT?

Tags: url, gwt, image

I want to check if a given URL exists and it's an image, in order to create a `new Image(String url)` from it. If the given URL is not an image then it should return an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this with a `RequestBuilder` -- just request the image URL, use the `Response`'s `getHeaders()` method to get the content type, and check if it's an image.

Answer (score 10):

I was looking for the same thing - I wanted to determine when image is not loaded from URL. There is an ErrorHandler for this purpose. Here's the code:

```
Image img = new Image("some_url/img.jpg");
img.addErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {                
    @Override
    public void onError(ErrorEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Error - image not loaded.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Image img = new Image(); //no url parameter
img.addErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {                
    @Override
    public void onError(ErrorEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Error - image not loaded.");
    }
});
img.setUrl("some_url/img.jpg"); // set the url after handler
```