# How to know if a URL of an image is Valid using GWT?

Tags: java, image, url, gwt

I am using google web toolkit, and I want to enter an URL in a textbox, and display the image from this URL on the page, so I use an ArrayList to handle my images, and a VerticalPanel, to display my images. So I want to add my image to my ArrayList and panel only when the URL is valid, and the data is an image.

I tried with image.addErrorHandler(), but it's not really what I want, I don't know how to use this, to stop the add of my image. So I saw this post [from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329831/how-can-i-check-if-the-given-url-of-an-image-exists-using-gwt) , but I don't understand how it works...

Thank you for your help !

Comment: `RequestBuilder` is probably what you want. Here's a slightly fleshed out example from [Gwt Request builder - how to return the response string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446161/gwt-request-builder-how-to-return-the-response-string). You make the request and supply a `RequestCallback` to handle `onResponseReceived` and `onError`. You display the image if a response is received/the url is valid. You display an error to the user on error.

Comment: I think the link in your post is the right solution.